# Como saber se o cliente já está aberto em outro computador?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, fluent-nhibernate

Estou fazendo um sistema que poderá e será aberto em possivelmente 2 a 7 computadores.
Existe uma preocupação do seguinte caso:

1. O PC1 abriu a ficha do cliente João e começou a editar.
2. O PC4 abriu a ficha do cliente João apenas para ver alguns dados.
3. O PC1 finalizou a edição e salvou.
4. O PC4 decidiu fazer uma pequena mudança na ficha e salvou também.

Nessa situação a alteração que vai prevalecer é a do PC4 que salvou a ficha por último, perdendo assim todos os dados alterados pelo PC1.

Que maneira posso utilizar para verificar se a ficha já está aberta? Levando em conta que a base de dados está numa rede local.

Existe alguma maneira inteligente e de baixo desempenho de fazer isso? Sem utilizar banco de dados para fazer consultas do tipo **"if (EmUso == true)"**.

Quem sabe algum arquivo, alguma comunicação direta entre os computadores. Enfim, aceito sugestões pra contornar este problema.

Comment: Existem N formas de se ter este controle. É uma aplicação desktop ou Web ? Qual framework está usando para acesso e persistencia de dados?

Comment: Se for uma aplicação web, você pode utilizar Application State: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx Por favor, especifique o tipo de aplicativo.

Comment: @Caputo Desktop, Fluent Nhibernate e MySql

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisando um pouco encontrei [este post do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272586/how-do-you-do-versioning-in-nhibernate)

do qual extraio a seguinte parte:

> **O usuário B seria capaz de ver o registro, mas ao tentar salvar daria um erro?**
>
> Isto aconteceria se [optimistic concurrency] estivesse sendo usada. No NHibernate, optimistic concurrency funciona adicionando um campo de **Versão**. Comandos de salvar/atualizar são enviados com o dado da versão na qual a alteração está baseada. Se a versão enviada for diferente da persistida, o NHibernate irá disparar uma exceção

Portanto, para protejer a situação, acredito que esta funcionalidade te ajude.

Caso queira criar sua própria solução, pode implementar uma trigger para controlar este número de versão no banco e na sua aplicação, de tempos em tempos, validar se o numero da versão na tela está diferente e notificar ao usuário, além de proteger a operação de salvar para validar a versão do registro.

Não encontrei material em português sobre a funcionalidade **optimistic concurrency**, se eu encontrar edito a resposta e adiciono aqui.

Comment: Pesquisarei sobre essa função, e se me ajudar, marco a resposta como correta